# javascript + preventDefault and stopPropagation not working in addEventListener

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I have form and using addEventListener for form submit, I am trying to stop the page loading after form submit.

Note: I want to use addEventListener function.

```js
var test = document.querySelector('.submit');
test.addEventListener('click', checkFunction);

function checkFunction (){
  console.log(test);
  this.preventDefault();
  this.`stopPropagation`();
}
```

```html
<form>
<input type="text" >
<input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" class="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: why have you got a "`" before and after stopPropagation?

Comment: @PaulFitzgerald most likely due to formatting of the post.

Comment: why have you add the ' after and before `stopPropagation()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `event` not `this`, where `event` refers to the event parameter which is passed to your callback function. In your case `this` just refers to the submit button.

**JSFiddle**

[Live Example](https://jsfiddle.net/v1kfx54y/1/)

Open the console to compare `e` (event) and `this`.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the `event` not `this` and will be work:

```
var test = document.querySelector('.submit');
test.addEventListener('click', checkFunction);

function checkFunction (event){
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();

    console.log(event);
}
```

I hope help you.